# WP_UnitTestCase - how to configure the include_path correctly with phpunit PHAR

Tags: wordpress, phpunit, composer-php

I'm trying to write a php unit test for my wordpress plugin and have been following the [writing-wordpress-plugin-unit-tests](https://codesymphony.co/writing-wordpress-plugin-unit-tests/) tutorial. I've cloned the '[core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tests/trunk/includes](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tests/trunk/includes/bootstrap.php)' locally

I have installed phpunit via the PHAR mechanism as described here : https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html#installation.requirements. I also have a composer.json configuration

```
[14:11:04@~]$ phpunit --version
PHPUnit 4.7.3 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
```

In my /etc/php.ini file i have

```
include_path="."
```

When i run my phpunit i get this error

```
[14:18:07@bhaawp]$ phpunit 
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php' (include_path='.') in /Users/pauloconnell/projects/bhaawp/wp-phpunit/bootstrap.php on line 7
```

The bootstrap.php file has this include

```
<?php
/**
 * Installs WordPress for running the tests and loads WordPress and the test libraries
 */
require_once 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php';
```

I think i need to add the phpunit folder to the path, but am having a mental block as to where this should be set to?

Comment: This might be better to ask on the [WordPress Development SE site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You should probably clone trunk/tests instead of tests/trunk. It makes a difference, because tests/trunk is old, and is no longer maintained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clone https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/tests/phpunit/includes/ instead. The one you are cloning is old and is no longer updated.

You will see that that line is no longer there in the [new bootstrap.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/tests/phpunit/includes/bootstrap.php).

Comment: Thanks - have pulled down the latest code but i still have the same error. Could you explain where the new bootstrap.php file is loaded from since the phpunit.xml is no longer referencing it.

Comment: @emeraldjava — The phpunit.xml needs to be referencing your own bootstrap file, which should in turn be including the "new" bootstrap.php file from WordPress.

Answer (score 2):

PHPUnit does not have a file named `PHPUnit/Autoload.php` (anymore).

If Wordpress' test suite and / or best practices for testing Wordpress plugins mention / use that file then this would be an indication for Wordpress relying on an outdated version of PHPUnit.

Comment: Thanks - might you have an example of the correct way that the PHPUnit library should be loaded? I've read the documentation on your site but it's still not clear what change i should make.

Comment: There is no need to load it. If you're using the PHAR you're all set because the PHAR's bootstrap takes care of it. If you're using Composer then you're using the autoloader generated by Composer.